How to align comment in algorithm code?
\usepackage{algorithm, algcompatible, algpseudocode}

    \begin{algorithm}\caption{Steps of computation in a full GN block}\label{alg:gn_block}
            \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            \Function{GraphNetwork}{$E, V, u$}
                \For{$k \in \{1 \dots N_e\}$}
                    \State $e_k' \gets \phi^e(e_k, E_{r_k}, E_{s_k}, u)$ \Comment{1. Compute updated edge attributes}
                \EndFor
                \For{$i \in \{1 \dots N_v\}$}
                    \State $E_i' \gets \{(e_k', r_k, s_k)\}_{r_k = i, k = 1:N_e}$
                    \State $\Bar{e}_i' \gets \rho^{e \to v}(E_i')$ \Comment{2. Aggregate edge attributes per node}
                    \State $E_i' \gets \phi^v(\Bar{e}_i', E_i, u)$ \Comment{3. Compute updated node attributes}
                \EndFor
                \State $E' \gets \{E_i'\}_{i = 1:N_v}$
                \State $E' \gets \{(e_k', r_k, s_k)\}_{k = 1:N_e}$
                \State $\Bar{e}' \gets \rho^{e \to u}(E')$ \Comment{4. Aggregate edge attributes globally}
                \State $\Bar{v}' \gets \rho^{v \to u}(E')$ \Comment{5. Aggregate node attributes globally}
                \State $u' \gets \phi^u(\Bar{e}', \Bar{v}', u)$ \Comment{6. Compute updated global attribute}
                \State \Return $(E', V', u')$
            \EndFunction
            \end{algorithmic}
        \end{algorithm}

This is the code I have.. I want the triangles to be exactly one below the other (like in the image), not that the comments are aligned to the right. 

Welcome to TeX.SX! Next time, it would be helpful if you could provide a complete minimal working example (MWE).

You can use the \makebox[width][position]{text} command to create a box of a specified width, allowing you to control the alignment of the text within it.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

\usepackage{algorithm, algcompatible, algpseudocode}
\usepackage{xcolor}% needed for the color 'blue'

\newcommand{\Bar}[1]{\bar{#1}}

% 0. this seems to be the package definition
% \renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{\hfill\(\triangleright\) #1}

% 1. let's align all comments to the right within a 7cm box
% \renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{\hfill\makebox[7cm][l]{\(\triangleright\) #1}}
% 2. let's use \fbox to visually check the box limits
% \renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{\hfill\fbox{\makebox[7cm][l]{\(\triangleright\) #1}}}

% 3. Bonus tip: let's make the comments stand out with different font and color
\newcommand\commentFont[1]{\small\ttfamily\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{\hfill\makebox[7cm][l]{\commentFont{// #1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}\caption{Steps of computation in a full GN block}\label{alg:gn_block}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Function{GraphNetwork}{$E, V, u$}
        \For{$k \in \{1 \dots N_e\}$}
            \State $e_k' \gets \phi^e(e_k, E_{r_k}, E_{s_k}, u)$ \Comment{1. Compute updated edge attributes}
        \EndFor
        \For{$i \in \{1 \dots N_v\}$}
            \State $E_i' \gets \{(e_k', r_k, s_k)\}_{r_k = i, k = 1:N_e}$
            \State $\Bar{e}_i' \gets \rho^{e \to v}(E_i')$ \Comment{2. Aggregate edge attributes per node}
            \State $E_i' \gets \phi^v(\Bar{e}_i', E_i, u)$ \Comment{3. Compute updated node attributes}
        \EndFor
        \State $E' \gets \{E_i'\}_{i = 1:N_v}$
        \State $E' \gets \{(e_k', r_k, s_k)\}_{k = 1:N_e}$
        \State $\Bar{e}' \gets \rho^{e \to u}(E')$ \Comment{4. Aggregate edge attributes globally}
        \State $\Bar{v}' \gets \rho^{v \to u}(E')$ \Comment{5. Aggregate node attributes globally}
        \State $u' \gets \phi^u(\Bar{e}', \Bar{v}', u)$ \Comment{6. Compute updated global attribute}
        \State \Return $(E', V', u')$
    \EndFunction
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}



You can set all the elements inside a box of equal width. This can be automated using eqparbox's \eqmakebox[<tag>][<align>]{<stuff>} that sets all <stuff> inside a box of maximum width across the same <tag>. An additional <align>ment can be specified.
The code below automatically defined the <tag> to be algorithm-dependent, so you can use it across different algorithms.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{eqparbox}

\NewCommandCopy\OldComment\Comment
% Update \Comment to utilize \eqmakebox[<tag>][<align>]{<stuff>}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\Comment}{m}{\OldComment{\eqmakebox[alg-\thealgorithm][l]{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Steps of computation in a full GN block}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Function{GraphNetwork}{$E, V, u$}
      \For{$k \in \{1, \dots, N_e\}$}
        \State $e_k' \gets \phi^e(e_k, E_{r_k}, E_{s_k}, u)$
          \Comment{1. Compute updated edge attributes}
      \EndFor
      \For{$i \in \{1, \dots, N_v\}$}
        \State $E_i' \gets \{(e_k', r_k, s_k)\}_{r_k = i, k = 1:N_e}$
        \State $\Bar{e}_i' \gets \rho^{e \to v}(E_i')$
          \Comment{2. Aggregate edge attributes per node}
        \State $E_i' \gets \phi^v(\Bar{e}_i', E_i, u)$
          \Comment{3. Compute updated node attributes}
      \EndFor
      \State $E' \gets \{E_i'\}_{i = 1:N_v}$
      \State $E' \gets \{(e_k', r_k, s_k)\}_{k = 1:N_e}$
      \State $\Bar{e}' \gets \rho^{e \to u}(E')$
        \Comment{4. Aggregate edge attributes globally}
      \State $\Bar{v}' \gets \rho^{v \to u}(E')$
        \Comment{5. Aggregate node attributes globally}
      \State $u' \gets \phi^u(\Bar{e}', \Bar{v}', u)$
        \Comment{6. Compute updated global attribute}
      \State \Return $(E', V', u')$
    \EndFunction
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}

Since \eqmakebox uses a \label-\ref-like approach to finding the widest element across the same <tag>, two compilations are needed with every change in the widest element (including the first compilation).

I was searching for this command but I didn't remember the name, thank you :)
